# How to set the hostname on a G1 Phone

Tags: android, hostname

I have a root'd G1 phone, and I would like to set its hostname. As root I can run the `hostname` command and set it, but the name does not survive reboot.

First, I tried creating a `/etc/hostname` file that only contained my hostname, but that did not work.

Next, I edited `/etc/hosts` like this:

```
127.0.0.1     g1-phone localhost
```

However that failed as well. Are there any other methods I can try to set the hostname permanently?

Answer (score 3):

Cyanogen ROM for Android phones includes a userinit.sh script that you can customize. The About page describes it as such:

```
Runs /system/sd/userinit.sh after A2SD setup and before starting the runtime for user scripts
```

http://www.cyanogenmod.com/about

I haven't tried putting the hostname command in there because I have read in the forums that it is easy to break that script and either brick or have to reset your phone.